# Which study guide is recommended for CAPM Certification?

Tags: project-management-style

I would like to know which study guide is recommended e.g 4th edition or 5th edition of the PMBOK GUIDE to prepare for my CAPM Certification?

Comment: Hey Kenny, why would you not think the newer edition is the one to go with? Can you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for information that is better available from the authoritative Source.

Answer (score 3):

You can check all the requirements on the [PMI's CAPM Exam Guidance page](http://www.pmi.org/Certification/Certified-Associate-in-Project-Management-CAPM/CAPM-Exam-Prep.aspx).

In the "Tips to Help You Prepare for the Exam" section, they say the following:

> Register for Essentials of Project Management — an online, self-paced course that offers a concentrated review of each Knowledge Area in the **5th edition PMBOK® Guide.** It also provides the contact hours needed to meet credential application requirements.

and they also say:

> Review the **latest edition** of A Guide to the Project Management Body of Knowledge (PMBOK® Guide).

Thus, according with PMI you must use the 5th edition PMBOK® Guide.

Comment: Hey FRM, welcome to Project Management SE. I edited this to pull in relevant content from the link you provided. It's best not to just post a link because links break, and now if the link were to break your answer would still be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the best guide besides PMBOK to be [Rita](http://www.rmcproject.com/product/capm-prep.aspx)